# Laravel 5.5 Rotas?

Tags: php, laravel

Não consigo achar o arquivo `routes.php` no Laravel 5.5 não esta dentro da pasta `http` só tem la dentro

```
http > controller/middleware/kernel
```

e isso que tem la dentro?

Comment: Não estará à procura do `routes/web.php` ?

Comment: Sempre bom ler a documentação do que está usando.

Answer (score 3):

Você deve estar utilizando documentação/tutoriais de versões anteriores. 5.4 em diante os arquivos de rotas ficam na pasta "routes". Veja em [Routing - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing). Nesse caso, você deve acessar a pasta routes/web.php para rotas de páginas .php